# call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't why I'm getting a `call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in pdo` error. It's really frustrating me!

```
$db= new PDO($dns,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$workspace_id=isset($_GET['workspace']) ? (int)$_GET['workspace'] : "";

try{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE workspace_id = :id";
  $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(':id', $workspace_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $result=$stmt->execute();
  $message=$result->fetch();
}catch(Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['workspace']`??

Comment: `$_GET['workspace']` returns an ID such as `356`

Comment: Just use `$stmt->execute();
  $message=$stmt->fetch();` and check

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)**

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

In your case you are try to fetch data form bool value

```
$result=$stmt->execute();
$message=$result->fetch();
```

Just need to change

```
 $stmt->execute();
 $message=$stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$stmt->execute()` should return `boolean` value.

If you want to use the fetch you should call method from `$stmt`

Documentation: [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

Comment: like this `$message=$stmt->execute()->fetch();`?

Comment: $stmt->execute();
$message=$stmt->fetch();